# Django Paginator doesnt work properly, how can i resolve

Tags: python, django, paginator

the django paginator data I use in my project does not work properly in sorting, for example, although I have records dated 2021 in my records, when I sort by date, it only sorts records dated 2020, here is my codes:

images;

[image]

after sorting;

[image]

about 2021 dated records finding by filtering;

[image]

views.py;

```py
gmembers_list = gunluk.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(gmembers_list, 1000000000000000)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    gmembers = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    gmembers = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    gmembers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'gunlukistakibi.html', {'gmembers': gmembers})a
```

html for listing;

```html
 <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
                Günlük İş Takibi
                <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{% url 'gcreate' %}" style="padding: 8px; float: right; background-color: green; color: white;">EKLE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive ">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center dataTable no-footer align-center align-middle " id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tarih</th>
                            <th>Ad Soyad</th>                       
                            <th>Vardiya</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Açıklama&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>İncident</th>
                            <th>Alınan</br>Aksiyon</th>                             
                            <th>Ulaşılamayan</br>Ekip</th>
                            <th>Ulaşılamayan</br>Bilgisi</th>
                            <th>Action</th>                               
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for gmember in gmembers %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{gmember.tarih|date:"d-m-Y"}}</td>
                                <td>{%if gmember.adsoyad2 == null%} {{ gmember.adsoyad}} {%else%} {{ gmember.adsoyad}} - {{ gmember.adsoyad2}}  {%endif%}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.vardiya }}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.aciklama }}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.incident }}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.alinanaksiyon }}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.ulasilmayanekip }}</td>
                                <td>{{ gmember.ulasilmayanbilgisi }}</td>                               
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="gedit/{{ gmember.id }}"> <span class="fa fa-edit"></span> </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="gdelete/{{ gmember.id }}"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any sorting by date in your code. Can you try with  `gmembers_list = gunluk.objects.all().order_by("-date")` (or whatever your date field on this model is named)?

By default, if you don't provide an ordering on the `Model.Meta` class, and no ordering when building your queryset, the sorting can be unstable depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any logic to tell django how to retrive the data from db. You either add Meta class to your model class

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    ....
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-datetime']      
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

or:

```
  gunluk.objects.all().order_by("-date")
```